# Discord.js | Making a message sniper command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot log/snipe a message, when someone says 'zsnipe', I want to know how would i make 'zsnipe' a command but its not working, am I doing something wrong? here's the code:

```
      bot.on('messageDelete', message => {
          
        const embed8 = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
          .setAuthor(`${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`, message.author.avatarURL({dynamic : true}))
          .setDescription(message.content)

      if (message.content === 'zsnipe'){
        message.channel.send(embed8)
      }
      })
```

Your Help Will be Appreciated!

Comment: https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#listening-for-messages You are listening on `messageDelete` instead of `message`.#

Comment: What do you mean by a *snipe* command?

Comment: A bot that can recollect the last message that was deleted and post what the deleted message was when someone says "zsnipe"

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that saves the last deleted message in a channel and allows it to be retrieved when someone says `zsnipe`.

**Warning:** *the deleted messages will be lost if the bot restarts.*

```js
const deletedMessages = new Discord.Collection();

bot.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.trim().split(/\s+/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  switch (command) {
    case 'zsnipe':
      const msg = deletedMessages.get(message.channel.id);
      if (!msg) return message.reply('could not find any deleted messages in this channel.');

      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(msg.author.tag, msg.author.avatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
        .setDescription(msg.content);

      message.channel.send(embed).catch(err => console.error(err));

      break;
});

bot.on('messageDelete', message => {
  deletedMessages.set(message.channel.id, message);
});
```